# how to handle soap response message?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I try to handle `<asd>'90'<asd>` this soap message but i get NPE while i try to handle.

Here is the WSDL :

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="asd" type="xsd:string"/>
```

and here is my JAVA code :

```
   @XmlElement(required = true)
protected String asd;
```

when i do `.getAsd()` i get NPE, What do i do wrong? I think problem is the response but i couldnt change it, i have to handle `<asd>'90'<asd>` response. what should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more of your JAVA code please? So we can see if it is annotated correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate it with @XmlRootElement?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "contentType", namespace = "unknown", propOrder = {
"asd"
})
public class MyClass {
  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected String asd;
}
```

Comment: Annotation is like : @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) but @XmlRootElement is missing should i add it ?

Comment: If you use a marshaller to read the Element you have to add it. Id would be easier to help you if you would provide more code.